# Rss feed images not responisve in mailchimp email template

Tags: css, rss, mailchimp, email-templates

Here is code of rss feed

*|RSSITEMS:|* *|RSSITEM:TITLE|* *|END:RSSITEMS|*

*|RSSITEMS:|* *|RSSITEM:IMAGE|* *|END:RSSITEMS|*
*|RSSITEMS:|* *|RSSITEM:CONTENT_TEXT|* *|END:RSSITEMS|*...

Images style are coming from blog site, i am not able to change,I have use css with important tag but not working please give me suggestions.

Comment: what error is there exactly

Answer (score 0):

according to https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/merge-tags/rss-merge-tags/

> *|RSSITEM:IMAGE|*
>
> Pulls in images from the RSS item. Images are pulled in and displayed
> at their original size. They can’t be formatted or resized within the
> campaign.

So they cannot be responsive :/

Answer (score 0):

[image: mailchimp rss campaign selection wizard]in the campaign selection, it says "We'll automatically resize the images in your RSS feed to fit the width of your template." but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this same problem this is how I solved mine.

In the RSS feed XML that's being generated by whatever language/framework you're using, make sure the image width is specified as "100%" so it can expand to the width of the container it's in when pulled into the Mailchimp template (usually a `<td>` tag). Then give the `<td>` tag whatever width you need it to have.

In my case I use Wordpress to generate the RSS feed. I have a PHP template called rssfeed-x.php, where "x" can be whatever you want the feed to have, could be a custom post type such as "event". Then in the template look for the RSS XML tag that has your image, usually `<media:content>`, and add the width and height attribute to it, like so:

```
<media:content url="image url here" medium="image" width="100%" height="auto">
```

Hope this will help.